# mongodb connection error causes kubernetes pod to hang and restarting the pod fixes the issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kubernetes

I have a nodejs app which uses mongodb and runs on k8s . But I am getting a problem whenever I change mogodb address, the k8s pod hangs and I've to restart to the pod to make it work again. So I think it happens because node service crashes at that time. 
How can I write my code to connect to mongodb in a way that the nodejs app doesn't crash when it fails to connect to mongodb or mondodb is down or something happens there.
My current code is

```
exports.connect = function() {
    return MongoClient.connect(mongourl);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

so, you want if mongo connection fails. it should not crash the app.
you can juust handle the `error` callback and do whatever you want.
in my case, i'm re connecting the DB, if its failing.
like below:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var connection = mongoose.connection;    

    connection
      .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log("Error in MongoDB Connection");
        console.error(err);
      })
      .on('disconnected', reConnect)
      .once('open', listen);

    connection.on('reconnected', function () {
      console.log('MongoDB reconnected!');
    });

    function connect() {
              const connection = mongoose.connect(<mongo Uri here >, <connection options>,(err)=>{
                    reConnect();
                  });
              return connection;
        }

        function reConnect() {

          if (mongoose.connection.readyState == 0) {
            console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);
            //you can just try to connect here now.
            // connect();
          }
          else {
            console.log("I am already Connected");
          }
        }
connect();
module.exports =  mongoose;
```

so i've used `mongoose` here, you can follow the way i have handled the error.in 
[Mongoclient Docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html) i saw, it supports callback as well. so you can probably handle the error in the same way. the properties like `.connection` and all those may not match though.

Comment: `exports.connect = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MongoClient.connect(mongourl)
            .then(db => {
                resolve(db);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                reject(e);
            });
    });
};`
will the above code work ?